# How to convert a mailable object to plain text version?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have an old `Laravel 5.7` application.

I have a mailable `Illuminate\Mail\Mailable object`.

I want to use a 3rd party to send my emails which is not within Laravel's default driver. For the API, I need to send the plain-text and the html-text of the mail.

I can retrieve html text like this:

```
$htmlText = $mailable->render();
```

But how to I retrieve the plain text?

This is my build of the mailable:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.newsletter.master')
                    ->text('emails.newsletter.master_text')
                    ->subject('Hallo');
}
```

I could not find how to retrieve plain text from mailable from Laravel docs. I also did not find a method inside the Mailable class that would generate the text.  I only see that the plain text  blade path gets assigned to textView variable.

Comment: this might help you https://github.com/soundasleep/html2text

Answer (score 0):

```
 $mailable->build();
 $text =  View::make($mailable->textView, $mailable->buildViewData())->render();
```

Explanation:

```
$mailable->build()
```

This makes sure that the `$this->text(...)` is called which will set the `textView` variable.

`$mailable->buildViewData()` converts public properties of mailable into an array.